# Getting error while running "./ejabberdctl status"

Tags: ejabberd

When I run the command "./ejabberdctl status", I get the following error:

```
Failed RPC connection to the node 'ejabberd@xyz.secureserver.net': nodedown

Commands to start an ejabberd node:
  start      Start an ejabberd node in server mode
  debug      Attach an interactive Erlang shell to a running ejabberd node
  iexdebug   Attach an interactive Elixir shell to a running ejabberd node
  live       Start an ejabberd node in live (interactive) mode
  iexlive    Start an ejabberd node in live (interactive) mode, within an Elixir shell
  foreground Start an ejabberd node in server mode (attached)

Optional parameters when starting an ejabberd node:
  --config-dir dir   Config ejabberd:    /opt/ejabberd/conf
  --config file      Config ejabberd:    /opt/ejabberd/conf/ejabberd.yml
  --ctl-config file  Config ejabberdctl: /opt/ejabberd/conf/ejabberdctl.cfg
  --logs dir         Directory for logs: /opt/ejabberd/logs
  --spool dir        Database spool dir: /opt/ejabberd/database/ejabberd@xyz.secureserver.net
  --node nodename    ejabberd node name: ejabberd@xyz.secureserver.net
```

---

Any way to find the root cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says the server is not running. The ejabberd node 'ejabberd@xyz.secureserver.net' cannot be contacted to retrieve the server status.

It could also be that your configuration is incorrect and you are not trying to contact the right node.